# Python with Selenium drop down list

Tags: python, selenium, select, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I cant get automate creating account with group_option selected using selenium with python. I tried several solutions but still it doesn't work. the website is form .php please see codes i used. Im on Linux not Windows.

test-1

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('group_option[]'))
select.select_by_value("Test")
driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
```

website.php

```
<select onchange="javascript:setStringText(this.id,'group')" id="usergroup" name="group_option[]" class="form" tabindex="105">
    <option value="">Select Groups</option>
    <option value=""></option>  
    <option value="Test"> Test </option>
    <option value="Test1"> Test1 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: @pguardiario im using Ubuntu server headless. what can you recommend?

Comment: I always use chrome because I like the console for debugging

Answer (score 2):

To select the option with text as **Test** you can use the following solution:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='form' and @id='usergroup'][contains(@name,'group_option')]"))
select.select_by_value("Test")
```

---

### Update

As you are still unable to select from the dropdown-list as an alternative you can induce *WebDriverwait* and use either of the following solutions:

- Option A:

  ```
  select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='form' and @id='usergroup'][contains(@name,'group_option')]"))))
  select.select_by_value("Test")
  ```
- Option B:

  ```
  select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='form' and @id='usergroup'][contains(@name,'group_option')]"))))
  select.select_by_value("Test")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: i tested the code and it didn't work. i don't know whats wrong

Comment: @nicollette16 Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('url')

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('usergroup'))
```

## select by value

```
select.select_by_value('Test')
```

Comment: im using driver = webdriver.PhantomJS() .. i tried your solution and still cant get result with group option. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('url')

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='usergroup']"))

# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text('Test')
 OR
# select by value 
select.select_by_value('Test')
```

Comment: tested this, i think i saw this same code from other solution and it didn't work