# Selenium window scroll works only in Debug mode identifying Select element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, html-select

I'm scraping a **VUE.js** website and when I have debug mode turned on in Selenium it can locate and click a drop down button but when I run it in normal mode it throws the following error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <select id="sortselectbox" data-ph-at-id="search-page-sort-drop-down" class="form-control au-target" value.bind="searchParams.sortBy" change.delegate="sortfilterSearch()" tabindex="0" data-ph-id="ph-page-element-page20-4VGGDW" au-target-id="169">...</select> is not clickable at point (707, 444). Other element would receive the click: <div class="chatBotNotificationText" tabindex="0">...</div>
  (Session info: headless chrome=96.0.4664.110)
```

Here's how I'm finding the dropdown button

```
Order = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='sortselectbox']")
```

Before that here's how I scroll to the top of the website so that the `sortselectbox` become visible for the driver

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 220)") #Page up
```

Here's the HTML element

```
<select id="sortselect" data-ph-at-id="search-page-sort-drop-down" class="form-control au-target" value.bind="searchParams.sortBy" change.delegate="sortfilterSearch()" tabindex="0" data-ph-id="ph-page-element-page20-UCZFWs" au-target-id="150"> <option value="Most relevant" key="c-internal-digital-technology-it-53pxnB-ph-search-results-v2-view4-mostRelevantText" data-ph-id="ph-page-element-page20-srcQGN"> Most relevant </option> <option value="Most recent" key="c-internal-digital-technology-it-53pxnB-ph-search-results-v2-view4-mostRecentText" data-ph-id="ph-page-element-page20-Br2Xo6"> Most recent </option> </select>
```

I've tried adding more sleep before and after the scroll but it seems it's failing at that step. All signs are indicating that scrolling doesn't work in normal mode. Would I have to find another way locating that `sortselectbox` button without the use of the `window.scrollTo` script?

Thanks!

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: Unfortunately the site is not publicly accessible and since it's in JS the source isn't static either.

Comment: I'm not asking for the site url either but the relevalent HTML of the desired element.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you I updated my original post with the HTML element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <select id="sortselectbox" data-ph-at-id="search-page-sort-drop-down" class="form-control au-target" value.bind="searchParams.sortBy" change.delegate="sortfilterSearch()" tabindex="0" data-ph-id="ph-page-element-page20-4VGGDW" au-target-id="169">...</select> is not clickable at point (707, 444). Other element would receive the click: <div class="chatBotNotificationText" tabindex="0">...</div>
```

...implies that the click attempt to the [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) element is obstructed by the **chatBotNotification**.

As the desired item is a [*Select*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69996583/selecting-options-using-selenium-and-python/69996687#69996687) element ideally [to select an option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53475998/python-with-selenium-drop-down-list/53478784#53478784) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#sortselect[data-ph-at-id='search-page-sort-drop-down']")))).select_by_value("Most relevant")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='sortselect' and @data-ph-at-id='search-page-sort-drop-down']")))).select_by_value("Most recent")
  ```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks! I learned a lot from your explanation and for pointing me to the appearing Chatbot which is causing the problem, now it works!