# Unable to find element in Python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to webscrape price list from a website and to do that I need to bypass age verification. To do that I am using following code to select the year "1999" but I am getting this error ----

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="year_field"]"}

---

### The code that I use:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

PATH="chromedriver.exe"


driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://valuebuds.com/pages/search-results-page")

driver.switch_to.frame("_hjRemoteVarsFrame")

time.sleep(5)

sel=Select(driver.find_element_by_name ("year_field"))

sel.Select_by_visible_text("1999")

print(driver.title)
```

Any help on this will be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) element for the year isn't within the [*iframe*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447). So you don't have to switch frames.

[image: valuebuds_iframe]

---

To select the *year* as ***1999*** using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) from the [dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252175/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://valuebuds.com/pages/search-results-page")
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#year_field")))).select_by_visible_text('1999')
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://valuebuds.com/pages/search-results-page")
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='year_field']")))).select_by_visible_text('1999')
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: valuebuds]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Selecting options using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69996687/7429447)
- [Python with Selenium drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53478784/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

The pop-up dialog is not inside a frame, so you should not switch to frame you are switching here.
Also you should use Expected Conditions explicit waits instead of hardcoded pauses.
And your locator is wrong, it is `year_field` `id`, not `name` attribute there.
This should work better:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

PATH="chromedriver.exe"


driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get("https://valuebuds.com/pages/search-results-page")

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "year_field")))
sel=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("year_field"))

sel.Select_by_visible_text("1999")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! However, when I try to run the above code, I receive the below error AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\SHEKHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_19120/340659611.py in <module>
     20 sel=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("year_field"))
     21 
---> 22 sel.Select_by_visible_text("1999")

AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'Select_by_visible_text'